# Ionic 5 / Appflow - Preparation failed during iOS Xcode 11 build

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, xcode11, ionic-appflow

I’ve an error when I build with iOS Xcode 11 on Ionic Pro Hub.

I do not know if the problem comes from **Ionic Appflow**, or from the code that I build. The problem appears in the build console of **Ionic Hub Appflow**.

> Running with gitlab-runner 10.2.0~beta.147.gbd1f3fcb (bd1f3fcb) on
>   ip-10-2-128-50 (c93ac604) Creating new VM… ERROR: Preparation failed:
>   The name ‘runner-c93ac604-project-0-concurrent-0’ already exists. Will
>   be retried in 3s … Creating new VM… ERROR: Preparation failed: The
>   name ‘runner-c93ac604-project-0-concurrent-0’ already exists. Will be
>   retried in 3s … Creating new VM… ERROR: Preparation failed: The name
>   ‘runner-c93ac604-project-0-concurrent-0’ already exists. Will be
>   retried in 3s … ERROR: Job failed (system failure): The name
>   ‘runner-c93ac604-project-0-concurrent-0’ already exists.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That error message says it is a system failure.

Is this on a self-managed GitLab instance?  Or a self-managed GitLab Runner server?

I notice the GitLab Runner version is out of date compared to what's on gitlab.com.

My jobs this morning on gitlab.com say:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.9.0 (4c96e5ad)
```

You have version 10.2.0~beta.147.gbd1f3fcb (bd1f3fcb)

Can you update to latest stable GitLab Runner?

Comment: Oh, I see. That's cool. I would contact Ionic support then about this issue -- like I said, it looks like a system error, not anything you did wrong. Let us know how it goes?